# Dragging a label or TextBox control onto a tabControl causes control to 'snap' back to its starting location

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I try to drag the label "Log" onto TabPage1, it snaps back to where it was.  Same for textbox to right of Log.

But dragging the Capture Session Management group stays on TabPage1.

[image]

Visual Studio 2017 Pro on Windows 10 Pro.
Me 1956.

I remember encountering this problem years ago, but can't remember the solution or problem cause.

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds like you are working with an inherited form where the tabcontrol is defined on the base form.  The only problem with this theory is that your image does not show the indicator glyph that the tabcontrol is part of the base form.

Comment: Not using inherited form.  I created the form, added controls, which all positioned and worked ok.  Later, added TabControl with 2 tabs added at design time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a bug in Visual Studio that's been around for many years.

The WORKAROUND (which I finally remembered) is simply to use the cursor keys to move the control instead of dragging.  Dragging causes Visual Studio 2017 (and earlier) to malfunction.

TIP:  Hold ctrl while tapping cursor keys to move to smart positions.  This might be faster than dragging, in the first place.